# Portability on all windows platform both 32 and 64 bit

Tags: c++, windows, portability

What should i care about when it comes to portability an all windows platform both 32 and 64 bit?
More over,if there's the necessity of using the windows APIs,what good habit should i have?

Comment: Did you consider using a framework library like [Qt](http://qt.io) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) ??

Comment: Without external library like these or Boost.

Comment: What about .NET? .. Otherwise, what exactly are you trying to do? WindowsNT based platforms (from 2k+) support the same basic WinAPI, and even then you still (usually) need to distribute your MSVCXXX.dll with your app unless you know it's installed with the system you're targeting or static link against it. Are you planning on using the CRT, MFC, the GDK, DirectX or any of the other Windows API/SDK technologies that they've come up with? Determine your goal and the answers might be more clear ..

Answer (score 0):

Don't know C++ but there is a simple and straight solution.
Put both 32 and 64 bit builds in a directory. And also place this bat file in there.

```
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="AMD64" GOTO x64
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%"=="AMD64" GOTO x64
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" GOTO x86
:x86
START "" build32.exe %1
GOTO arcselend
:x64
START "" build64.exe %1
:arcselend
exit
```

Even if you want to do after execution actions (after program exits) also welcomes

```
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="AMD64" GOTO x64
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%"=="AMD64" GOTO x64
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" GOTO x86
:x86
START "" /W build32.exe %1
GOTO arcselend
:x64
START "" /W build64.exe %1
:arcselend

:: Do something here like
DEL /F/Q "-PATH-\sometempfile.tmp" >NUL 2>NUL

exit
```

You don't want bat files around?
[Here](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) we have a bat 2 exe compiler with an extremely small footprint. In the settings you can define to start your app with elevated privileges also.

Note: Use relative path (sure) and if you have any problem about paths write here. There will be another simple solution.